# How to change php5 to php 5.6 version on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.3, php-5.6, apache2.4

I'm on server using ubuntu 14.04 and also already install both php 5.5 and 5.6 version, after looking to phpinfo() i know php located in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (now using this path) and /etc/php/5.6

The question is how i can change the path apache "Loaded Configuration File" to /etc/php/5.6 ?

My apache is in /etc/apache2 now using 2.4.7 version, please help anyone? i've been searching for days but not finding solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php5.5
$ sudo a2enmod php5.6
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```